# Laravel: Apache alias for URLs with trailing slash

Tags: apache, laravel

I have a Laravel website in directory `/home/user/Documents/laravel-training`.

I would like to visit my website from `http://localhost/dev/`,
so I set an alias in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

Here is my `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.example.net

    ServerAdmin foo@example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /dev /home/user/Documents/laravel-training/public
    <Directory /home/user/Documents/laravel-training/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I also added `RewriteBase /dev` to the beginning of `/home/user/Documents/laravel-training/public/.htaccess`.

Now, I can visit my website successfully in case the URL does not ends with a slash.

For example, if I add the following route:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Then I can visit it from `http://localhost/dev/test`.

But if my URL is `http://localhost/dev/test/`, the server will incorrectly redirect my page to `http://localhost/test`, and causes a 404 Not Found error.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

---

In response to Stefano Ortisi's comment:
I did not change anything else in `.htaccess`. I just kept the default settings.

```
RewriteBase /dev

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: have you double checked your .htaccess inside the public folder of laravel is working?

Comment: @StefanoOrtisi I didn't modify anything else. I've updated my post.

Comment: Try moving your `RewriteBase /dev` directive after your `RewriteEngine On` directive.

Comment: @patricus I've tried it, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an error that it redirects without the trailing slash.

In your `public/.htaccess` as you can see there is the following lines:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

^^^ as the comment states that will redirect a url with a trailing slash if it is not a folder. If you remove that you will see it will not redirect you.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I'm not familiar with Apache configuration files.