# Laravel Trailing Slashes redirect to url with public. how to solve it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

If i try to go to url https://example.com/admin/page, laravel correct redirect me to https://example.com/admin/page.

But if I try to go to https://example.com/admin/page/, with trailing slash, I'm redirected to https://example.com/public/admin/page.

I'm try to use this `.htaccess` on the root of project but it didn't worked

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I would like to redirect to https://example.com/admin/page even if I go to https://example.com/admin/page/.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You're using the same url with `/` for another thing? Or, when you try to access some route on your `/admin/` you cannot access? Please, provide more information about that.

Comment: Maybe [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509546/laravel-apache-alias-for-urls-with-trailing-slash)

Comment: If i try to go to url like: https://example.com/page/about, laravel correct redirect me to https://example.com/page/about, but if i try to go to https://example.com/page/about/, with trailing slash, i'm redirected to https://example.com/public/page/about

it's problem when page interlinking https://example.com/page/about/ and big problem is xml sitemap crawling my site and search engine index this url: https://example.com/public/page/about